# FileOutputStream zip file open ERROR: "File cannot be opened as an archive"

Tags: java, zip, fileoutputstream, bytearrayoutputstream

I am trying to create ".zip" file from byte array but the error given appear everytime I am attempt to open it. Here is the code:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class ReadTxtFile {

public static void BinFileContToBinArr(String path) throws Throwable{
    BufferedReader inputStream = null;
    PrintWriter outputStream = null;

    try{
        String el = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        FileOutputStream  fos = new FileOutputStream("D:/texttNE22W.zip");
        while((el=inputStream.readLine()) != null){
            baos.write(el.getBytes());
        }
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        for(int i = 0; i<b.length; i++){
            System.out.print((char)b[i] + " ");
        } 
        fos.write(b);           
    } 
    finally{
        if (inputStream!=null){
            inputStream.close();
        }
        if(outputStream!=null){
            outputStream.close();
        }           
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    String path = "D:/text.txt";
    BinFileContToBinArr(path);

}
}
```

I've made a research but didn't find a solution. Also, I tried to create a ".txt" file and it works. The only problem is when it comes to creating a ".zip".

Thank you beforehand ! By the way, if someone have encountered this problem before, feel free to vote up or leave me a comment if you wish, because I am interested if it is a common mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [ZipOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) instead of FileOutputStream.

Comment: Thank you! However in the book where I am studying it says to use  FileOutputStream and I am interested in that solution.

Comment: So the book is asking you to manually implement zipping? You need to replicate the functionality of ZipOutputStream without using it? You need to write an implementation of the Zip algorithm? That's not very trivial, you might want to start your research here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29

Comment: Well, yea. Thank you, I will definately start from here... :)